# How to exclude rewrite for a specific file and rewrite all other request to the same file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is my requirement,

any request that comes to http://subdomain.example.com should rewrite to execute http://subdomain.example.com/script.php

But any request comes directly to http://subdomain.example.com/script.php should not be redirected/rewrite anywhere else.

How can i make this without ending on a rewrite loop?

Answer (score 1):

> any request that comes to `http://subdomain.example.com` should rewrite to execute `http://subdomain.example.com/script.php`.
>
> But any request comes directly to `http://subdomain.example.com/script.php` should not be
>   redirected/rewrite anywhere else.

If I understood right, you may try this in one .htaccess file at `subdomain.example.com` root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$    /script.php         [L,NC]
```

Not only the requests to `script.php` will be excluded from the rule and passed through, but any other request with something in the URI-path as it has to be empty for the rule to be used.